# no line found exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Help again guys, why do I always get this kind of error when using scanner, even though I'm sure that the file exists.

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

I am trying to count the number of occurences of `a` by using `for` loop. the text file contain lines of sentence. At the same time, I want to print the exact format of sentences.

```
Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/input.txt"));
while (scanLine.nextLine() != null) {
    String textInput = scanLine.nextLine();
    char[] stringArray = textInput.toCharArray();

    for (char c : stringArray) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'a':
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(scanLine.nextLine() != null) {
    String textInput = scanLine.nextLine();
}
```

I'd say the problem is here:

In your `while` condition, you scan the last line and come to EOF. After that, you enter loop body and try to get next line, but you've already read the file to its end. Either change the loop condition to `scanLine.hasNextLine()` or try another approach of reading files.

Another way of reading the txt file can be like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("text.txt")))));

String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // do something with your read line
}
reader.close();
```

or this:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("text.txt"));
String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: +1 for the first part of your answer, and for the second part, you've used too many unnecessary wrappers. Instead, use this `new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("text.txt")));`

Comment: Not necessarily. If he wants to use difference encoding/charsets, then InputStreamReader is needed. But in general, yes, you're right, the code should be concise when it can :D +1

Answer (score 2):

You should use : scanner.hasNextLine()  instead of scanner.nextLine() in the while condition

Scanner implements the Iterator interface which works by this pattern:

- See if there is a next item (hasNext())
- Retrieve the next item (next())

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of occurrences of "a" or for that matter any string in a string, you can use StringUtils from [apache-commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/index.html) like:

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.countMatches(textInput,"a"));
```

I think it will be more efficient than converting the string to character array and then looping over the whole array to find the number of occurrences of "a". Moreover, StringUtils methods are null safe